# What wireless mice work well with Ubuntu?

Tags: mouse

I'm in desperate need of a decent comfortable mouse that will give me maximum performance on Ubuntu. I'm looking at a wireless Microsoft mouse, but I am concerned it will not work effectively with Ubuntu.

Is there a list of wireless mice that are confirmed to work well with Ubuntu?

Is there a place where I can get opinions from Ubuntu users about mice?

Comment: Edited to fit the format of the site. Subjective questions are better discussed at a forum like http://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: I've seen quite a few reports that Microsoft mice working perfectly under Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you looking for a mouse for your desktop or laptop?

Comment: @Oxwivi : Can you cite at least of the reports you've seen? It would be helpful to see what they say exactly.  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Here's a list of mice that were certified to work under Ubuntu:

- [**Mouse Components**](https://web.archive.org/web/20161002062129/http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/MOUSE) (in Wayback Machine)

Comment: Certified list (58 peripherials contained) is really narrow compared to the real working hardware list.
I do understand that certified means perfectly working but imho you just lose the chance of choosing :)

Comment: @Pitto just working doesn't mean it works consistently with all features supported. Most of wireless mice don't show charge level, change their backlight or something like that out of the box in Ubuntu

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev While I do agree I still think that 58 (fiftyeight) mouses is surely a smaller number than the 100% compatible mice out there

Answer (score 12):

All mice, keyboards and joysticks produced these days follow the **USB HID** specifications so should all ***"just work"*** out-of-the-box on Ubuntu.

Some very specialist input devices, such as multiple-device tablets, might require tuning to a particular user's preferences but will generally be available in a basic mode as soon as they are plugged in, or selected and paired via the Bluetooth menu.

Apple and high-end wireless mice/keyboards tend to come with Bluetooth support directly.  Other wireless devices often arrive with a very small USB adaptor/receiver unique to that manufacturer’s devices, but should still "just work".  (Until the battery runs out!).

Comment: This is mostly true apart from mice with many additional user buttons, in which case all the normal functionality will work just fine and only the specialist bits will give any trouble.

Answer (score 7):

Try the official ubuntu mouse! http://shop.canonical.com/
If that doesn't work with ubuntu, nothing will!

Answer (score 5):

In my experience 100% of mice I've tried work perfectly with Ubuntu.

I use a Logitech MX Revolution and I'm really happy with its outstanding wheel.
It's a lot of money for it so if you want to spend less mx518 is a great great mouse.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [Configuring a Multi-Button Mouse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto) .

Answer (score 2):

I like Logitech Marble Mouse. You'll need to add a section to your xorg config file though.

Comment: /Gödel -- I've not had to change xorg for my marble mouse, though I may not have enabled some features.  What did you have to modify?

Comment: typically to add scrolling via small left button + ball, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1288288/285057

Answer (score 1):

[Logitech Anywhere Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002QUZM0U)
It just has, 3 clicks, smooth scroll (easy turn-off-able), back and forward button. Biggest selling point is "anywhere", it runs on any surface. Plus a tiny usb connector to your laptop.
And it just works perfectly as soon as you attach to ubuntu. No configurations required.

Answer (score 1):

I used several Models of Logitech and was always very happy with them.

Answer (score 0):

I am extremely happy with the [Logitech G9X](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice/devices/5092), which is not only the best mouse for Ubuntu (works out of the box) but on any platform, it's customizable, it's also the most comfortable to hold. (it has wires, but that doesn't get in my way, it's super responsive) It's an expensive gamer's mouse but it's worth every penny!

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for a mouse to support nice copy-and-paste-of-text
on Linux for over 7 years now.

I recently found the best candidate so far --- a Logitech 't400' mouse.

I am not the only one who has been lamenting the lack of such a mouse.
There are many engineers, graphics artists, 3D modeling artists, and
video effects people who have been searching for such a mouse.

About 10 comments from such people are collected at the following web page

http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Hardware/MiceAndOtherPointers/LogitechMouse_t400/LogitechMouse_t400.htm

along with some information on the mouse.

Here is a typical comment under the forum-posting title:

'Good. Could be great for Pros.'     March 1, 2013

"This is the first real 3 button mouse [the Logitech t400] that I've found
in a long time. As a VFX [video effects] professional, I use middle click
just as much as most people use left and right click. There are so many
people that use middle click everyday and are stuck using ancient mice
from the 90's or contorting their fingers to use the scroll wheel.
I bought the T400 because it looked like the old style 3 button mice,
and I was so pleased to find that it truly works like a traditional 3
button mouse. BRAVO!" --- from www.logitech.com/en-us/product/

Comment: This is an awful mouse, the "paste" functionality is provided by pressing down the "scroll wheel". On this T400 however, only the bottom part provides this functionality. The upper and middle part act as a keyboard button. If I was to suggest a mouse, I would say the M525, it also features back/forward button which is very useful when surfing the web.