# How do I get my right- and middle-click back?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, mac, multi-touch

I just upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04.1 on my Macbook 7,1 and the first thing I noticed was that I couldn't right-click by clicking on the clickpad with two fingers, or middle-click by clicking with three, as I had been. According to everywhere, there's now "better clickpad support" but the only thing I see is that things have stopped working. How can I get things back to the way they were? Note that I **do not** want to right-click by clicking on the bottom-right area of the clickpad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `synclient`.

```
synclient ClickPad=0 # Even though I'm using a clickpad, this
                     # setting inhibits multi-finger click.
synclient ClickFinger3=2 # Add the 3-finger click in order to
                         # middle click.
```

Everything now works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Apple hardware but I'd try opening a terminal and running `xev`. If you place your cursor over the white window and click buttons, you'd at least see if the xserver is receiving those events at all.

Then, I'd probably personalise the keys using xinput, as I did suggest [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79195/where-do-i-have-to-paste-an-xinput-command-so-that-it-executes-it-when-gnome-i/201825#201825).

Comment: No; when I click with two or three fingers the event is not listed.

Comment: In the interest of this bounty not going to waste, I'm going to award it to you if nothing better pops up in the next day as this answer did at least let me know that the problem was earlier in the event chain than X. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad you sorted this and happy if this tip helped a little. I don't use touchpads or Apple hardware but when it comes to issues with xorg and events, xev is pretty helpful. Also thanks for mentioning synclient.