# .profile xinput issue

Tags: bashrc, mouse-scroll, xinput, .profile

On Ubuntu 16.04 lts my Logitech wireless mouse scroll speed is too high, so I intended to use the following row in the `~/.profile`:

```
xinput set-prop 9 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' 8 1 1
```

as suggested earlier in a workaround in this forum.

But if system boots, I get the error:

> "unable to find device 9"

.
However if I insert the row into the `.bashrc` it works fine, but thus if I wanted to use my mouse with the smoother scroll behavior inside of Unity, first I need to start terminal to execute `.bashrc`, which is not too practical.

Any idea?

Comment: See [Where do I have to paste an “xinput” command so that it executes it when GNOME is started?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79195/where-do-i-have-to-paste-an-xinput-command-so-that-it-executes-it-when-gnome-i)

Comment: @steeldriver For now the only method works, if I run the terminal and then run the 'xinput set-prop' with the required options. I tried Marcin's https://askubuntu.com/questions/79195/where-do-i-have-to-paste-an-xinput-command-so-that-it-executes-it-when-gnome-i script, Startup Application but those didn't work unfortunately.